# Combine csv rows having similar values in python

Tags: python, dataframe

I need to extract and combine multiple rows which have the same value of the first column into a single row. Input csv looks like below:

source:

```
20191111,test7,10,0,0,0
20191111,test6,0,9,0,0
20191111,test5,0,0,8,0
20191111,test3,0,0,0,7
20191111,test2,0,0,0,0
20191111,test1,0,0,0,0
20191110,test7,0,0,0,0
20191110,test6,0,0,0,0
20191110,test5,0,0,0,0
20191110,test3,0,0,0,0
20191110,test2,0,0,0,0
20191110,test1,0,0,0,0
```

```
target:

20191111,test7,10,0,0,0,test6,0,9,0,0,test5,0,0,8,0, .....
20191110,test7,0,0,0,0,test6,0,0,0,0,test5,0,0,0,0, .....
```

Comment: Sure thing, that's not hard. What have you tried so far?

Comment: There are three parts to this: read the CSV file into a Python data structure, transpose the Python data structure, and write the Python data structure into a new CSV file. Which piece are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this oughta work. No pandas were harmed writing this code.

```py
import collections
import csv
import io
import itertools
import sys

file = io.StringIO(
    """
20191111,test7,10,0,0,0
20191111,test6,0,9,0,0
20191111,test5,0,0,8,0
20191111,test3,0,0,0,7
20191111,test2,0,0,0,0
20191111,test1,0,0,0,0
20191110,test7,0,0,0,0
20191110,test6,0,0,0,0
20191110,test5,0,0,0,0
20191110,test3,0,0,0,0
20191110,test2,0,0,0,0
20191110,test1,0,0,0,0
""".strip()
)

groups = collections.defaultdict(list)
for row in csv.reader(file):
    groups[row[0]].append(row)  # storing the full row here, for greater reusability

out = csv.writer(sys.stdout)

# NB: `groups` aren't (necessarily) in any sorted order;
#     could add e.g. `sorted(groups.items())` here to sort by the key
for group_key, rows in groups.items():
    # Build the transposed row from the group key, then the rows sans the first column of each
    transposed_row = [group_key] + list(itertools.chain(*[row[1:] for row in rows]))

    # Write to the CSV writer; you could append to a dataframe or anything else here.
    out.writerow(transposed_row)
```

Comment: Thank you for your information, your code is working good for your input  but when I added it in my script, I am getting: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'csv'
What is the possible reason that I get this error? "Please note that I am new in programming :)

Comment: I don't know how you "added it into your script", so it's hard to help. Nothing in the code here would attempt to access a `.csv` attribute.

Comment: with open("TRA_Stats.csv", encoding='utf-8' ) as f:
        reader = csv.reader(f)
        TRACSVList = []
        for row in reader:
            TRACSVList.append(row)


    groups = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for row in csv.reader(TRACSVList):
        groups[row[0]].append(row)

Comment: That code isn't reading a `.csv` attribute either. Post your full new code as a new question, along with the error and the line it points to, etc.

Comment: Comment field does not allow me to copy full part. How can I share with you?